# Syncfusion MAUI dataForm CheckBox, Date item's Label doesn't Appear in LeadingView

Tags: c#, maui, syncfusion, dataform

I am using VS 2022, .NET 8.0, MAUI app with Syncfusion UI controls.

For the Boolean and Date type Property in my Model Class -> DataAnnotation I have assigned Name to the property as

```
[Display(GroupName = "Other Info", Name = "Working Status")]
public bool WorkingStatus { get; set; }

[Display(Name ="SysDate")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "dd-MMM-yyyy")]  //doesn't change format
[DataFormDateRange(DisplayFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy")]  //no effect either
[ReadOnly(true)]
public DateTime SysDate { get; set; }
```

but the said name Caption doesn't appear If DataFormItem LeadingView is Generated.
[image: Without Leading View]
[image: With Leading View]

I am expecting a Label / Caption to appear along with Items